# NEXP = Σ$_2$ ⟹ NEXP = MA?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

Is it known whether the implication $\mathsf{NEXP} = \Sigma_2 \implies \mathsf{NEXP} = \mathsf{MA}$ holds?

(The question is inspired by well-known $\mathsf{NEXP} \subseteq \mathsf{P/poly} \Leftrightarrow \mathsf{NEXP} = \mathsf{MA}$.)

Comment: Posted to [cstheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17646/is-it-known-that-nexp-sigma-2-implies-nexp-ma)

Comment: Did you get anywhere? If it's an open problem, an answer to that effect may be appropriate.

Comment: One could get a different (and as far as I know, still open) question by replacing $\Sigma_{\hspace{.03 in}2}$ with ​ [SBP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:S#sbp) $\cap$ [S$_{\hspace{.02 in}2}$P](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:S#s2p) . ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 1):

This is not known.

$NEXP = \Sigma_{2}$ means that $NP$ and $NP^{NP}$ are different. But, $MA$ seems too weak to reach that high to catch $NP^{NP}$.